# Error "can´t pickle local object" al intentar serializar una instancia

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialización

Tengo el siguiente código que básicamente crea una serie de "registros" creando instancias de la clase `personas` a partir de los datos ingresados por el usuario. Estas instancias a su vez son almacenadas en una instancia de la clase `listaspersonas` la cual intento serializar y deserializar pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "main.py", line 53, in <module>
>     registro()
>   File "main.py", line 50, in registro
>     agregarregistros()
>   File "main.py", line 28, in agregarregistros
>     pickle.dump(lista,archivo_almacenamiento)
> AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'registro.<locals>.listaspersonas'
> ```

Este es el código:

```
def registro():
  import pickle
  class personas:
    def __init__(self,nombre,genero,edad):
      self.nombre=nombre
      self.genero=genero
      self.edad=edad
      print("se ha registrado a una nueva persona")

    def __str__(self):
      return"nombre: {} ,genero: {}, edad: {}".format(self.nombre,self.genero,self.edad)

  class listaspersonas:
    lista_personas=[]

    def agregarpersonas(self,p):
      self.lista_personas.append(p)

    def mostrarregistrosactuales(self):
      print("estos son los registros del momento")
      for c in self.lista_personas:
        print(c)

  def agregarregistros():
    archivo_almacenamiento=open("registro de personas","ab")
    pickle.dump(lista,archivo_almacenamiento)
    print("se han guardado los registros")
    archivo_almacenamiento.close
    del(archivo_almacenamiento)

  def mostrarregistrosarchivados():
    archivo_almacenamiento=open("registros de personas","rb")
    registros_imprimibles=pickle.load(archivo_almacenamiento)
    print("se han cargado los archivos")
    archivo_almacenamiento.close()
    del(archivo_almacenamiento)
    print(registros_imprimibles)


  lista=listaspersonas()
  while True:
    p=personas(input("nombre: "),input("genero: "),int(input("edad: ")))
    lista.agregarpersonas(p)
    pregunta=int(input("¿continuar?: 1)si 2)no "))
    if pregunta==2:
      break
  lista.mostrarregistrosactuales()
  agregarregistros()
  mostrarregistrosarchivados()
```

Comment: Hola. Bienvenid@ a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando mas información, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que tu clase `listaspersonas` no está definida a nivel global sino que la defines dentro de una función. Si nos vamos a la propia [documentación de pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) nos encontramos con:

> 12.1.4. What can be pickled and unpickled?
>
> The following types can be pickled:
>
> - `None`, `True`, and `False`
> - integers, floating point numbers, complex numbers
> - strings, bytes, bytearrays
> - tuples, lists, sets, and dictionaries containing only picklable objects
> - functions defined at the top level of a module (using def, not lambda)
> - built-in functions defined at the top level of a module
> - classes that are defined at the top level of a module
> - instances of such classes whose `__dict__` or the result of calling `__getstate__()` is picklable (see section Pickling Class Instances for details).

La clave está en "*classes that are defined at the top level of a module*", es decir, son *picklables* **solo aquellas clases definidas de forma global a nivel del módulo.**

Si seguimos leyendo la documentación nos da la explicación:

> Note that functions (built-in and user-defined) are pickled by “fully
>   qualified” name reference, not by value. [2](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) This means that only the
>   function name is pickled, along with the name of the module the
>   function is defined in. Neither the function’s code, nor any of its
>   function attributes are pickled. Thus the defining module must be
>   importable in the unpickling environment, and the module must contain
>   the named object, otherwise an exception will be raised. [3]
>
> Similarly, classes are pickled by named reference, so the same
>   restrictions in the unpickling environment apply. Note that none of
>   the class’s code or data is pickled.
>
> These restrictions are why picklable functions and classes must be
>   defined in the top level of a module.
>
> Similarly, when class instances are pickled, their class’s code and
>   data are not pickled along with them. Only the instance data are
>   pickled.

Traducido libremente:

> Tenga en cuenta que las funciones (las integradas y las definidas por
>   el usuario) se **serializan mediante la referencia al nombre completo**, no por
>   valor. [2](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) Esto significa que **solo el nombre de la función está**
>   **serializado, junto con el nombre del módulo** en el que está definida la
>   función. Ni el código de la función ni ninguno de sus atributos de
>   función están serializados. Por lo tanto, **el módulo dónde son**
>   **defininidas debe ser importable en el entorno dónde se deserializa**, y
>   **el módulo debe contener el objeto nombrado**; de lo contrario, se
>   generará una excepción. [3]
>
> De manera similar, las clases se serializarán por referencia al
>   nombre, por lo que se aplican las mismas restricciones en el entorno
>   de deserializado. Tenga en cuenta que ninguno de los códigos o datos
>   de la clase está serializados.
>
> Estas restricciones explican por qué las funciones y clases
>   serializables deben definirse en el nivel superior de un módulo.
>
> De forma similar, cuando las instancias de clase son serializadas, el
>   código y los datos de su clase no se serializan junto con ellos. Solo
>   los datos de la instancia son serializadas.

Por lo tanto, dado que definir una clase dentro de la función si no tienes una buena razón para ello no es ni lo más legible ni eficiente, simplemente define tu clase a nivel del módulo, con lo que no tendrás problema alguno al serializar. La función puede crear instancias de la clase sin problemas, no necesitas para nada que sea definida localmente.

Por cierto, te recomiendo mirarte las convenciones de estilo definidas en [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), especialmente en cuanto a los nombres de clases, variables/atributos y funciones/métodos y al identado del código. solo son convenciones, pero hacen tu código más legible.

Tu código podría quedar por tanto algo así:

```
import pickle



class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, genero, edad):
      self.nombre = nombre
      self.genero = genero
      self.edad = edad
      print("se ha registrado a una nueva persona")

    def __str__(self):
      return "Nombre: {}, género: {}, edad: {}".format(self.nombre, self.genero, self.edad)


class Personas:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lista_personas = []

    def agregar_persona(self, persona):
        self.lista_personas.append(persona)

    def mostrar_registros_actuales(self):
        print("Estos son los registros del momento:")
        for persona in self.lista_personas:
            print(persona)


def guardar_registros(path, obj):
    with open(path, "ab") as f:
        pickle.dump(obj, f)
    print("Se han guardado los registros")


def cargar_registros_archivados(path):
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        registros = pickle.load(f)
    print("Se han cargado los archivos")
    return registros


def registro():
    lista = Personas()
    while True:
        p = Persona(input("Mombre: "),
                    input("Género: "),
                    int(input("Edad: ")))

        lista.agregar_persona(p)
        pregunta = input("¿Continuar?: 1)Si 2)No ")

        if pregunta == "2":
            break

    lista.mostrar_registros_actuales()
    guardar_registros("registros_de_personas.pkl", lista)
    reg = cargar_registros_archivados("registros_de_personas.pkl")
    print(reg) # reg es una instancia de Personas, como lista
    reg.mostrar_registros_actuales()

registro()
```